# Display the total number of hours by each Activity

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I'm trying to make a SELECT statement based on the table below that will display specific rows as well as the total number of hours by each Activity has been done for.

```
Employee Details    Activity Details           Week Number  Hours Worked
1   Clyde            163    Sales and Marketing       39     10
1   Clyde            163    Sales and Marketing       40      8
1   Clyde            163    Sales and Marketing       42      6
1   Clyde            151    Web Design                41      5
1   Clyde            151    Web Design                42      5.5
2   Sally            155    Python Coding             39      10
2   Sally            165    Testing                   39      15
2   Sally            155    Python Coding             42      10
2   Sally            165    Testing                   40      20
2   Sally            155    Python Coding             41      10
5   Tara             155    Python Coding             39      8
5   Tara             155    Python Coding             40      6
5   Tara             155    Python Coding             41      5
5   Tara             151    Web Design                42      11.5
6   Mike             151    Web Design                39      1
6   Mike             151    Web Design                40      1
6   Mike             151    Web Design                41      1
```

This is my code so far. Everything is fine except for the calculation for the amount of hours spent for each activity.This code gives this error: single-row subquery returns more than one row.I know this code has an error but I thought it would be the clearest way to show you.

```
 SELECT a1.ActId,a2.Description,(SELECT SUM (HrsWorked) from ACTION GROUP BY ActId) AS "Total Hours",a1.HrsWorked * a3.HourlyRate AS "Total Pay"
FROM ACTION a1
INNER JOIN ACTIVITY a2 ON a1.ActId = a2.ActId
INNER JOIN ALLOCATION a3 ON a1.EmpId = a3.EmpId;
```

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: It's not clear to me why `select Description, sum(HoursWorked) from Activity group by Description ;` doesn't answer your question. Please add expected output given the above input. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use window functions for what you want:

```
select a.*,
       sum(hoursworked) over (partition by activity) as totalhours
from action a;
```